# Magento - 'New Products' list on homepage incorrectly showing all products

Tags: magento

I'm experiencing an issue with Magento's product list.

On the homepage, I have a block with 3 tabs that show new products, top rated products, and most reviewed products.

This was working fine until I set a large number of products to be no longer new. As in I cleared the 'new from' and 'new to' in the product settings.

After doing this, I started experiencing the following behavior:

All 3 tabs now show **all** products regardless of whether or not they are actually new, have ratings, or have reviews. They simply just load all the products - which causes a significant delay in loading times.

I would appreciate any insight into this behavior. Is there a specific cache I need to manually clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

1. Navigate to System > Index management and reindex data.
2. Go to System > Cache management and refresh all cache.

You can also clear cache manually by deleting content of **/var/cache/** folder